# VBA - Accessing html tag inside html tag

Tags: vba, dom

I'm new to VBA. My goal is to access a site and put my login details into it automatically. This will be the first step into ripping info from reports and putting them in a spreadsheet.

I'm unable to show the site due to privacy issues. Work related.

But the DOM Hierarchy goes like this, name/id/class are the attributes they have.

Html, Frameset name, Frame name, Html, Body id class, div class, form name id, table, tbody, tr, td, div, div id, input id name class (id and name are both username)

I've been able to access the Frame via

```
 WebBrowser.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")
```

but haven't been able to access the input element with

```
 WebBrowser.document.getElementById("username")
 WebBrowser.document.getElementName("username")
 WebBrowser.document.getElementTagName("input")
```

I've been counting the returned elements in a debug.Print method.

My question is how do I access the input element in this hierarchy.

If anyone has some good resources on VBA and Automation I would apprecaite that also.

Cheers

Comment: Better to show your actual code, and the actual HTML.

Comment: Yeah still new at the work place and they are full on with privacy and IP etc so just trying to play it safe... Hard to give a good question with that restriction. :(

Comment: The elements you want are not part of the top-level document, but part of the document hosted in the frame.  Once you have a reference to the frame, you can get a reference to its document object and go from there.